# Thinkpad E460 touchpad not detected

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, alps

This is a fairly new model and I understand support isn't going to be great from the get go.

External mouse does work.
I have tried Ubuntu 14.04, 15.10, and 16.04, Mint 17, and Opensuse (Leap and Tumbleweed). All have failed to detect the ALPS touchpad in this laptop. I have tried kernel updates to the newest 4.5 RC7, but it failed to detect the touchpad. (xinput)

I have read others reporting little to no mention of issues with the touchpad. At one point the touchpad did work in Ubuntu 15.10 but after either a kernel update or software update it had stopped working. Even after a fresh reinstall the touchpad failed to work. I can't seem to mimic my 15.10 install to get it working.

Bios on the laptop has been updated to the latest 1.12.

Do I need to file a bug report? Are there any other possible solutions I could try?

Answer (score 9):

I found a fix for anyone else who is having this issue.

1. First get into terminal and type `gksudo gedit etc/default/grub`.
2. Next, the `grub.cfg` file should pop up. Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` and within the quotes type in `i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop`.

   So it should look like this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
   ```

   Hit save.
3. Next, you need to open up another terminal window and update grub by typing in `sudo update-grub` and finally restart.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 daily with 4.5 RC7. Credit goes to MrZackehhSoul.

Comment: Works in mint 17.3 but Mint doesn't play nice with gedit. You'll end up with a blank .cfg file.  So in order to edit grub.cfg, you need to use nano instead.  Then you can edit the file from within terminal.

Comment: Worked here too. Thanks. Could you link the source?

Also, there's a missing "/" before "etc"

> sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

Comment: excellent. I got this issue updating from 1.13 to 1.17 to fix the sticky keys issue with charger plugged in. However I just tried putting in `i8042.reset` in the kernel command line and that worked. I did it based on some hints from lenovo support that the bios settings should be reset.

Comment: first check if the .Xauthorization file is present in your root directory.
For me, there was no such file and it thre an error: Unable to copy the user's .Xauthorization file.

in this case, run 'touch .Xauthorization' and set r/w permissions and then follow the content of this post.
Worked for me!

[see here: https://sourceforge.net/p/peerguardian/bugs/325/]

Comment: Here's more information about this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/what-does-the-i8042-nomux-1-kernel-option-do-during-booting-of-ubuntu